# Noisy customized exhausted motorcycle pipe

Tags: single-word-requests

In Thailand, some of bikers customize his exhausted pipe to increase noise pollution and it is extremely loud!

What is the brief and concise with negative wording for them?

Comment: Offensive; intrusive; harmful? There must be 37 other terms but ELU is here to help after you've explained what your own dictionaries or thesauruses failed to make clear. Could you post what research you did, and how far that got you?

Comment: 'Exhausted' in your title question is interesting. Usually and colloquially this refers to someone who is very tired, exhausted by exercise. It does not usually describe a vehicle that is fitted with an exhaust, though I suppose it could do (say, in a technical manual). But the wording 'noisy, customised motorcycle exhaust' is apt, descriptive and expressive. I would stay with it, myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a vulgar expression for these in the US: fart can, from the resemblance between the exhaust noise and flatulence.

This is a relatively new coining, and I haven't found this cited in a reputable dictionary yet (other than Urban Dictionary).  But an internet search for [fart can](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1249&bih=628&ei=7vCKW-WkEaHUjwTtnYboBA&q=fart%20can&oq=fart%20can&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i67l2j0l8.141239.141239..141599...0.0..0.102.102.0j1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71.43QLqhbWk8E) will show discussion of this in automobile and motorcycle enthusiast forums.

Answer (score 0):

They call it Sport exhaust system. If you want to describe the sound in a disapproving way there are a lot of words like aggressive, fakery, overdone travesty . . .  i saw them in some car wesites.

Comment: What john said was a nice word. Here is the definition from urban dicfart can
The type of annoying muffler found on many pos compact cars today. Often capable of setting off car alarms and deafening infants. Most pitiful sounding on cars with automatic transmission.
Can you hear it, its a rice rocket coming; you can hear the fart can on it half a mile away.